# How to show add one row of a mysql Table?

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Hi i want to show all the data of one row in a table.But i can only show 1 column of the table.

```
function getAllRecipes(): array {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recipe";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

$recipe = getAllRecipes();

<?php foreach ($recipe as $recip) : ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?= **$recip["id"];** ?></td>  <----here
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the result
[image]

and i want all of the line:
[image]

Do you know how to do it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: ```<td><?= **$recip["title"];** ?></td>``` and repeat for all of the columns

Comment: You want to show all values from different columns in differnt <td>'s?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes

Comment: Is it only possible by repeating the td?

Comment: You already did one column there.  Why not add the other columns???

Comment: I thought it was possible to add all the column without repeat the td. BUt someone told it is an obligation. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on "i just want by one line show all the contain of th row" in your "answer".

```
$arr_values = array_values($recipe);
$html = '<table><tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>', $arr_values) . '</tr></table>';
echo $html;
```

If you simply only want the name of the keys(columns):

```
$arr_keys = array_keys($recipe);
$html = '<table><tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>', $arr_keys) . '</tr></table>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: No problem.  Im glad I could help!